# Return value for XML column without XML tags

Tags: json, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to find the value of a specific field in an XML column without using convert or cast in SQL Server 2016, however the XML does not contain traditional tags. I'm not too familiar with XML data so I'm trying to understand how to best accomplish this.

I've tried using `[column].value`, however I'm not able to return a result because I can't figure out how to identify the nodes without tags.

Here's the query I'm running:

```
select customeridentifier, customerdemographics 
from customerdatafile
```

The customerdemographics column is xml which appears like:

```
{  
  "request": {  
    "customer_id": "12345efg"
    "ip_address": "12.1.4.12"
    "name.value": "JAMES"
  },
  "customer_compatibility": 40
}
```

I'm looking to return the value for "customer_compatibility", which I've tried to accomplish via something like:

```
customerdemographics.value('(customer_compatibility)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

which returns a null value. On the other hand,

```
customerdemographics.value('(.)','nvarchar(max)')
```

returns the full value of the XML field without issue.

What would be the most efficient way of returning the value for `customer_compatibility` from the XML column? Worst case, I can do a cast/convert but due to the data size, queries would be slow.

Comment: That's **NOT** XML - that's JSON :.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the `customerdemographics` column seems to be in `JSON` format (although there are missing `,` between the `key: value` pairs). SQL Server 2016 supports `JSON` and you may try to parse this `JSON` using `JSON_VALUE()` (to extract a scalar value from a `JSON` string) and `OPENJSON()` (a table-valued function that parses `JSON` string and returns objects and properties as rows and columns).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE customerdatafile (
   customeridentifier int,
   customerdemographics nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO customerdatafile 
   (customeridentifier, customerdemographics)
VALUES
   (1, N'{"request": {"customer_id": "12345efg", "ip_address": "12.1.4.12", "name.value": "JAMES"}, "customer_compatibility": 40}')
```

Extract a single value:

```
SELECT 
   customeridentifier, 
   JSON_VALUE(customerdemographics, '$.customer_compatibility') AS customer_compatibility
FROM customerdatafile
```

Parse the whole JSON:

```
SELECT d.customeridentifier, j.*
FROM customerdatafile d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.customerdemographics) WITH (
   customer_id nvarchar(100) '$.request.customer_id',
   ip_address nvarchar(100) '$.request.ip_address',
   [name.value] nvarchar(100) '$.request."name.value"',
   customer_compatibility int '$.customer_compatibility'
) j
```

Results:

```
customeridentifier  customer_compatibility
1                   40

customeridentifier  customer_id ip_address  name.value  customer_compatibility
1                   12345efg    12.1.4.12   JAMES       40
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you are trying to access `customer_compatibility` as `root` node. tried to convert you `json` to `xml` and modified your `xpath`, seems working fine.

```
declare @strJson xml = '<test><root>
   <customer_compatibility>40</customer_compatibility>
   <request>
      <customer_id>12345efg</customer_id>
      <ip_address>12.1.4.12</ip_address>
      <name.value>JAMES</name.value>
   </request>
</root></test>'


select @strJson.value('(//customer_compatibility)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you really have JSON

```
declare @j varchar(1000);

set @j = '{  
  "request": {  
    "customer_id": "12345efg",
    "ip_address": "12.1.4.12",
    "name.value": "JAMES"
  },
  "customer_compatibility": 40
}';

print JSON_VALUE(@j, '$.request.customer_id');

select * from openjson(@j);
select * from openjson(JSON_QUERY(@j, '$.request'));
```

note that I added commas to your string